# Scala factory with type classes

Tags: scala

I have a class holding a collection:

```
import scala.collection.mutable._
class Data[T](x: Buffer[T])
```

I also want to create a factory object. The easiest thing I can do (ignoring case classes) is the following:

```
object Data {
    def apply[T](x: Buffer[T]): Data[T] = new Data(x) 
}
```

and in code I can decide on the actual Buffer implementation, eg.

```
scala> Data(ListBuffer.empty[Int])
res0: Data[Int] = Data@1537e43
```

So far so good. However, is there a way to play around with types in the companion object so that you don't need to instantiate the Buffer outside, but rather have it done in the `apply` itself?

I could make one solution work, using reflections:

```
import scala.collection.mutable._
import scala.reflect._

class Data[T](x: Buffer[T])

object Data { 
    def apply[T](x: Buffer[T]): Data[T] = new Data(x)
    def apply[T, B <: Buffer[T]: ClassTag]() = 
        new Data(
           classTag[B]
               .runtimeClass
               .newInstance()
               .asInstanceOf[Buffer[T]]
        )
}

Data[Int, ListBuffer[Int]]()
res1: Data[Int] = Data@2c16677c
```

Needless to say this one is fairly ugly. Is there a way to have the call like `Data[ListBuffer[Int]]()`?

Edit: Scala version **2.11.12**

Comment: Which is your **Scala** version?

Comment: Version: 2.11.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what [`CanBuildFrom`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.12/scala/collection/generic/CanBuildFrom.html) is for (given that you're on Scala < 2.13):

```
class Data[T](val x: Buffer[T])

object Data {
  def apply[T](implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[T, T, mutable.Buffer[T]]): Data[T] = {
    new Data[T](cbf().result())
  }
}

object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val data = Data[ListBuffer[String]]
    val otherData = Data[ArrayBuffer[Int]]

    println(data.x.getClass)
    println(otherData.x.getClass)
  }
}
```

Yields:

```
class scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
class scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
```

Comment: It would be good to add imports, apart from that this doesn't work in the sense that `data` is not a **Data[String]** is a **Data[ListBuffer[String]]**.

Comment: Indeed it does exactly what I needed, really nicely solves it. Funny enough, I thought I recognized your name, and indeed it was only a few hours ago that I was reading your speark streaming blog post. Nice read, appreciate writing it up.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **Scala** `2.13` you can use the new `Factory` for this.
If you are in an older version, you can do something similar using `Builder`.

```scala
object Data {
  def empty[T, C[x] <: Buffer[x]](implicit f: Factory[T, C[T]]): Data[T] =
    new Data(f.newBuilder.result())
}
```

Which you can use like this:

```scala
val data = Data.empty[String, ListBuffer]
data.x.addOne("X")

val otherData = Data.empty[Int, ArrayBuffer]
otherData.x.addOne(0)
```

---

*You can see the code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/Okk7INyRSM6FRqcKmUdB6w/11)*.

Comment: Very interesting, also I feel like the syntax with Factory is more intuitive and readable than CanBuildFrom.

Answer (score 0):

Along with other suggestions, I suggest adding an `apply` method that takes a variable number of arguments:

```
object Data {
  def apply[T](data: T*) = new Data(Buffer(data:_*))
}

Data(1,2,3)
Data("A", "b", "c")
Data(List(2,3,4):_*)
```

Comment: Hi Tim, in this case you would drop to default Buffer implementation, and not have it parametrized that way. Having multiple apply would do that I suppose, but then you need to implement different versions for all Buffer implementations you have/want to use.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, but you could retain the original `apply` if you like, but the goal is to avoid having the implementation exposed in the interface. The user of `Data` does not need to know that it is implemented using `Bufffer`.

Comment: True - though my initial idea was to leave it up to the user to choose which particular implementation.